# Pyqgis. The nearestNeighbor() function returns different number of items than requested (qgis 2.18.2)

Tags: pyqgis

I have this chunk of code(inside a loop), where I request 6 nearest elements from a spatialIndex, but I'm getting different numbers of elements, sometimes 6, another 7, another 8... is very strange.

```
nearest_ids = target_spatial_index.nearestNeighbor(center,6)
if log:
    logging.info('Center: '+str(center))
    logging.info("Total nearest:"+str(len(nearest_ids))+'->'+str(nearest_ids))
```

Log:

```
...
Center: (125051,4.38048e+06)
Total nearest:8->[6L, 14L, 7L, 15L, 19L, 16L, 20L, 8L]
Center: (123452,4.379e+06)
Total nearest:8->[5L, 13L, 18L, 2L, 10L, 7L, 15L, 19L]
Center: (124261,4.38087e+06)
Total nearest:6->[7L, 15L, 19L, 16L, 20L, 8L]
Center: (123265,4.37567e+06)
Total nearest:7->[1L, 9L, 17L, 11L, 3L, 2L, 10L]
...
```

Can anyone confirm it? (Yes, see my answer below)

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any overlapping? Did you try to check this result without using PyQGIS (for example, with the **Join attributes by location** tool)?

Comment: Thank's HowToInQGIS, Not necessarily an overlap must occur, it is enough that the other several objects are at the same distance.

Answer (score 1):

I respond myself. nearestNeighbor handle a Rtree to get items,  looking into the source of RTree.cc 
(https://svn.osgeo.org/qgis/trunk/qgis/src/core/spatialindex/rtree/RTree.cc) you can see this line:

```
void SpatialIndex::RTree::RTree::nearestNeighborQuery( long k, const IShape& query, IVisitor& v, INearestNeighborComparator& nnc )

....

      // report all nearest neighbors with equal greatest distances.
      // (neighbors can be more than k, if many happen to have the same greatest distance).
      if ( count >= k && pFirst->m_minDist > knearest ) break;
```

So nearestNeigbour can return more items than requested if they are at the same distance